# osmdroid GoogleTilesOverlay smooth resize zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, osmdroid

Following the Google Tile Wrapper example, I have implemented a google MapView with an osmdroid GoogleTilesOverlay.

```
    com.google.android.maps.MapView googleMapView;
    org.osmdroid.google.wrapper.MapView osmdMapView;
    org.osmdroid.google.overlay.GoogleTilesOverlay tiles;

    final MapView googleMapView = (com.google.android.maps.MapView.MapView) findViewById(R.id.plan_mapview);
    osmdMapView = new org.osmdroid.google.wrapper.MapView(gMapView);

    // snip Provider instantiation etc.

   overlayTiles = new GoogleTilesOverlay(provider, getApplicationContext());
   gMapView.getOverlays().add(overlayTiles);
```

At rest, the overlay tiles render fine however when zooming (pinch or via the controls) the underlying google tiles resize and are replaced smoothly however the osmd overlays aren't resizing.

The result: when zooming in the tiles that remain in view begin to overlap. Conversely when zooming out a gap becomes visible between each tile.

It looks to me like the first step is to sub-class GoogleTilesOverlay so that I can modify the draw() method. But then what?

I've googled hard and found a few pointers towards:
a) short-circuiting out of the draw() method when in the middle of an animation
b) using the Projector / Matrix classes to determine how to scale the overlay on the fly

Unfortunately I'm not an expert on the Android APIs so not sure which way to go... and then how to best implement a solution.

Comment: can i ask exactly what it is you're trying to achieve?  i know the google maps android API is really poor, and OSMDroid provides much better functionality, but why are you trying to have 2 x mapViews on the screen at once?  that seems wrong.  I may be able to help with whatever the problem is as i've just finished writing an app myself that uses OSMDroid, with local tile overlays etc, so i've had to delve quite deep into the OSMDroid code.

Comment: Semi-transparent tiles, overlaying the base (google) map. For instance, pre-computed tiles that highlight certain landmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a slight modification on the draw method in `GoogleTilesOverlay`.

As it is draws a rectangle of a constant size `(x,y,x+tileSizePx,y+tileSizePx).`

Easy and rudimentary way to do it, just get two tiles `(x,y and x+1,y+1)` and Subtract the difference in pixels.

*Look below code:*

```
                final GeoPoint geoPointUL = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Mercator.tile2lat(y, zoomLevel) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Mercator.tile2lon(x, zoomLevel) * 1E6));                    

                final GeoPoint geoPointLR = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (Mercator.tile2lat(y+1, zoomLevel) * 1E6),
                        (int) (Mercator.tile2lon(x+1, zoomLevel) * 1E6));

                Point pointUL=new Point(), pointLR=new Point();
                pj.toPixels(geoPointUL, pointUL);
                pj.toPixels(geoPointLR, pointLR);
                tileSizePx = pointLR.x - pointUL.x;
```

Comment: This does the trick! Although the Mercator class is now deprecated.

Comment: @dwightgunning Do you know what should be used in place of Mercator?

Comment: No it doesn't appear there's any replacement. I've seen it used in new code in 3.0.8 so I guess the timeline for removal isn't defined.